# Removing double quotes from passed parameters in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I'm trying to copy specific files from a directory with sub directories. I have listed the file names in a text file. And because of spaces in the file names I used a quote to enclose the for loop variable %%a below.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (G:\TestRename\List.txt) do (

for /r "G:\TestRename\" %%I in ("%%a") do copy /y %%I "G:\TestRename\ListDocs\" 
)
pause
```

However when the %%a parameter is passed to %%I the quotes remain despite trying / to escape. Not sure of how to properly pass file names into %%I without double quotes. Can anyone kindly assist?

My text files contains filenames like

```
1_test of Out_2feb24_1.pdf

2_test of in_2feb24_2.pdf

3_test_2feb24_1.pdf
```

Comment: copied from `for /?`:  `%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")`

Comment: @Stephan can you pls elaborate more?

Comment: do this on the command line: `for %i in ("teststring") do @echo %i %~i "%~i"` (double the `%` when using in a batchfile). Should be self-explaining.

Answer (score 1):

There is a construct for this:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (G:\TestRename\List.txt) do (
    for /r "G:\TestRename\" %%I in ("%%~a") do copy /y %%I "G:\TestRename\ListDocs\"
)
```

The tilde operator removes double quotes and then quotes are added to protect spaces in %%a.

It might be that this won't work on loop variables. Then you can write:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (G:\TestRename\List.txt) do (
    set "name=%%a"
    for /r "G:\TestRename\" %%I in ("%~name%") do copy /y %%I "G:\TestRename\ListDocs\"  
)
```

Comment: it does work with loop variables. But it doesn't work with ordinary variables.

Comment: @user1016274. I have tried both approach but still not passing files names correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
SET THE_LIST=^
 "line 1" ^
 "line2" ^
 "line 3" ^
 line4

ECHO the list = %THE_LIST%

FOR %%a IN (%THE_LIST%) DO (
    ECHO plain variable = %%a
    ECHO quotes removed = %%~a
    ECHO quotes removed and put back = "%%~a"
    ECHO ===
)

C:>lt.bat
the list =  "line 1"  "line2"  "line 3"  line4
plain variable = "line 1"
quotes removed = line 1
quotes removed and put back = "line 1"
===
plain variable = "line2"
quotes removed = line2
quotes removed and put back = "line2"
===
plain variable = "line 3"
quotes removed = line 3
quotes removed and put back = "line 3"
===
plain variable = line4
quotes removed = line4
quotes removed and put back = "line4"
===
```